# convert string to symbol and use in if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of "options". I need to assess each option and set them as being true or false.

So I started with

```
    if params[:account][:use_dbs].present?
      if params[:account][:use_dbs] == '1'
        @account.settings.use_dbs = true
      else 
        @account.settings.use_dbs = false
      end
    end

    if params[:account][:use_time_logs].present?
      if params[:account][:use_time_logs] == '1'
        @account.settings.use_time_logs = true
      else 
        @account.settings.use_time_logs = false
      end
    end
```

and this actually works fine. However, I'm going to end up with 20 or so options and I don't want to repeat myself 20 times. So then I thought about doing something like this...

```
    # handle optional screen settings
    options = ['use_dbs', 'use_time_logs']
    options.each do |option|
      if params[:account][(option.to_sym)] == '1'
        @account.settings.option.to_sym = true
      else
        @account.settings.option.to_sym = false
      end
    end
```

which would obviously be a lot neater but I cannot get my head round the required syntax. Can someone please help?

Comment: What is `@account.settings`?  Ie what type of object?

Comment: If `@account` is an active record object and `use_dbs` and `use_time_logs` are bit columns you can just assign them directly and rails will handle typecast: `@account.assign_attributes(params[:account])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! The thing that I think is giving you trouble is how to call methods dynamically (i.e. your `@account.settings.use_time_logs=` call). You can do that using [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send). Note that you need to add an `=` onto the end of the attribute name (when you do `object.attr=` you're actually calling a method called `attr=` on `object`).

As @Stefan points out, you can put the boolean condition in as a value directly, and your life will also be made a lot easier through using symbols instead of strings (why bother with `to_sym` all the time?)

So:

```
# handle optional screen settings
options = [:use_dbs, :use_time_logs]
options.each do |option|
  @account.settings.send("#{option}=", params[:account][option] == '1')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the first obvious thing to say is "why not just use symbols in the first place?"

```
options = [:use_dbs, :use_time_logs]
options.each do |option|
  if params[:account][option] == '1'
    @account.settings.option = true
  else
    @account.settings.option = false
  end
end
```

Secondly, this is not quite the same as your first one:  in the first code, if the option isn't present in params you don't set it to anything.  In the second lot of code, you set it to false.  I don't know if this is important.

I think this could actually be further tidied up by doing it like so:

```
if params[:account]
  params[:account].each do |k,v|
    @account.settings.send("#{k}=", v == "1")
  end
end
```

Comment: Using the first set of code I get an error "undefined method `option=' for #<AccountSetting:0x007fe62ac32dd8>". If I set @account.settings.use_dbs = true it works, but @account.settings.option = true doesn't. Can you think of an obvious reason why?

Comment: Can you answer my comment above asking what "settings" is? thanks